Canada transit visa when you have work W-1 visa
I am an Indian citizen traveling from USA to India and back via Toronto (Canada). My layover in Toronto is for 4 hours. I already have a multiple entry work W-1 visa for Canada and an H-4 visa for USA, do I need a transit visa? Thank you.
